# TaskExecutionException on grails upgrade to 3.3.10 bootrun

Tags: grails, upgrade

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
 What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
 Process 'command /home/shrshrestha/.sdkman/candidates/java/8.0.222.hs-adpt/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
* Exception is:

Comment: i am trying to upgrade grails from 3.1.4 to 3.3.10 but i got  an issue above mentioned on boot on and following exception
 Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.

Comment: Please provide the full stack trace - also take a look at the diff between a 3.1.4 app and a 3.3.10 app to make sure you upgraded everything needed - https://github.com/erichelgeson/grails-versions/compare/3.1.4...3.3.10#files_bucket